# Appcenter can't update system component

Tags: appcenter, system, update-manager

Appcenter can't update even though I've tried to update multiple times. It still shows that there is 1 component to update. Also tried to update in command line, it says everything is up to date. How can I fix this?

[image: Appcenter screenshot]

Comment: Can you please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in Terminal and then add the output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

OK DUDES & DUDESS'S! I got you..
I had the exact same issue, and I finally found this on a reddit post.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential
```

last one is the trick!! enter all in terminal, with your password, and awesome..